# Does IE10 have an audio API?

Tags: audio, internet-explorer, signal, internet-explorer-10

Is there any way to do any audio processing(FFT,etc.) with javascript in Internet Explorer ?

Does anyone know if IE10 does/will have any audio processing apis (similar to the [Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) one) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it does. [Still](http://www.phoboslab.org/log/2011/03/the-state-of-html5-audio).